# Getting key of sorted properties in Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to return the key of the first object returned by the `_.orderBy()` method which sorts by a nested property.

[Here is the CodePen demo.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LzjKLJ?editors=0012) In this case, the key I want to return is `"charlie"`.

```
console.clear();

const ob = {
  "alpha": {
    "id": 27,
    "lottery": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "La Primitiva",
      "jackpotAmount": 500,
    }    
  },
  "bravo": {
    "id": 28,
    "lottery": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "La Primitiva",
      "jackpotAmount": 10,
    }    
  },
  "charlie": {
    "id": 29,
    "lottery": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "La Primitiva",
      "jackpotAmount": 1000,
    }    
  },  
}

const out = _.orderBy(ob, (e) => {
  return e.lottery.jackpotAmount;
}, ['desc'] ); // How do I get key of first property, "charlie"?

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't the most efficient way of getting the highest jackpotAmount. Sorting is O(n log n ). You can find the highest value in O(n) time. This is also creating a temporary copy of the list so it uses a lot of extra memory for a temporary operation. Using _.maxBy() would be more efficient.

```
var x = _.maxBy(ob, (e) => { return e.lottery.jackpotAmount; });
return x.id;
```

These functions work on lists. To get the key rather than item, you need to iterate over the keys.

```
var keys = Object.keys(ob);
return _.maxBy(keys, (e) => { return ob[e].lottery.jackpotAmount; });
```

Note that this doesn't entirely solve the efficiency issues. Depending on the javascript engine, the overhead of needing the keys array and the ob[e] lookup degrade space usage to O(n) and potentially a complexity of O(n log n).

If you're targeting a modern JS engine, you can use the Map object with a hand-written search to get constant space and linear time search.

```
const getMax = function (map) {
    let maxValue = null;
    let maxKey = null;

    map.forEach((value, key) => {
        if (value.lottery.jackpotAmount > maxValue) {
            maxValue = value.lottery.jackpotAmount;
            maxKey = key;
        }
    });

    return maxKey;
};
```

Here's a [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RLLNNP?editors=0012).

Cheers

Comment: Nice idea. Just a small correction - you need to use `_.minBy()`, because `_.min()` doesn't accept a callback. In addition, as the user wants the highest `jackpotAmount` value (sort is descending), use `_.maxBy()`.

Comment: It works using `_.max()`. [Here's the pen.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gGxVyG?editors=0012)

Comment: @OriDrori -- Ah, sorry, good catch. I was thinking of the underscore min(), not the lodash min(). I've updated the code in the answer.

Comment: @Mowzer - it works because in the array of `['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie']`, `charlie` has the highest value. The callback is ignored. Change  `alpha` to `delta`, and see what happens.

Comment: @OriDrori: You are correct about changing to `delta`. But `maxBy()` does not appear to work either. [Here is the demo.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gGGYvj?editors=0012) What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also removed my mention of using sortBy. That was also for underscore. Either is acceptable in lodash. Though again, for efficiency reasons, we still don't want to use it for this.

Comment: This will work `var x = _.maxBy(keys, (e) => ob[e].lottery.jackpotAmount);`

Comment: @Mowzer Grab the updated code from my response. I made some edits after you copied it to the Codepen.

Comment: @OriDrori: Solved. Confirmed. [Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gGGYvj?editors=0012)

Comment: Looks good. I updated the answer for max rather than min, as you wanted the greatest jackpot.